# Reading from an Arduino tty with FILE*

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, arduino

As far as I can see, one of the best sources for figuring out how to read and write to the `/dev/serial/by-id/*arduino*` dev node is this link:

http://todbot.com/blog/2006/12/06/arduino-serial-c-code-to-talk-to-arduino/

However, his `serialport_read_until` smells suspicious. Isn't `serialport_read_until(fd, buf, '\n')` the same as `fgets(buf, bufsize, fptr)` ? In other words, what's stopping me from using `fdopen` on the file descriptor to get a `FILE *fptr`, and then using `fgets` / `fscanf` / `fgetc`?

I've tried this approach. The writing calls like `fputc` work, but the read calls fail out with `errno = 0`.

The init code:

```
devfd = open(dev, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
int devfl = fcntl(devfd, F_GETFL);

// Serial/terminal options
termios termopts;
if (tcgetattr(devfd, &termopts))
    throw;

// No parity; No flow control; One stop bit
// Select 8 data bits
// local ownership; read enabled
termopts.c_cflag = CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD;
// No canonical features; raw mode; no echo
termopts.c_lflag = 0;
// No input processing features; raw mode
termopts.c_iflag = 0;
// No output processing features; raw mode
termopts.c_oflag = 0;

if (cfsetispeed(&termopts, B115200)) // 115200 baud in
    throw;
if (cfsetospeed(&termopts, B115200)) // 115200 baud out
    throw;

// Read timeout
termopts.c_cc[VTIME] = 10; // Time out after 1s
termopts.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;   // Wait for each character

if (tcsetattr(devfd, TCSANOW, &termopts))
    throw;

devf = fdopen(devfd, "r+");
if (!devf)
    throw;
```

Writing and reading functions:

```
void dputc(char comm)
{
    if (fputc(comm, devf) == EOF)
        throw;
    if (fflush(devf))
        throw;
}

void dputs(const char *str)
{
    if (fputs(str, devf) < 0)
        throw;
    if (fflush(devf))
        throw;
}

void dprintf(const char *str...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, str);
    int n = vfprintf(devf, str, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    if (n < 1)
        throw;
    if (fflush(devf))
        throw;
}
```

The reading code:

```
unsigned short f;
if (fscanf(devf, "%hu", &f) < 1)
    throw;
```

Any idea why reading like this would fail?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the sender putting a carriage return at the end of the line? So that fscanf knows the entry has finished

Comment: Yes, the sender issues \r\n .

Comment: (I am not an Arduino expert) Seems to me that the read returns early if nothing can be read, to avoid blocking on read (called non-blocking mode on UNIX) The stdio-buffering you lay upon it wants to fill a buffer of data, at least a line. The premature return (should be -1: EAGAIN) confuses the buffering layer. Maybe fdopen() is not such a good idea. Or you might have to tweak some more flags... As a last resort, you could add your own buffering, at least for input (I don't know if fdopen() allows to be bypassed in one direction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this. There were many problems:

- On OpenSuse 11.2, the group for `/var/lock` is wrong. It's set to `root` when it should be `lock`.
- I was part of neither the `lock` nor `dialout` groups.
- The Arduino automatically reboots every time that the driver behind `/dev/ttyACM*` sees a new file handle. This Arduino Uno takes quite a long time after the handle is open to be accessible ( > 1s ). This is fixed by sending a boot message from the Arduino and waiting for it in the Linux client after the file handle is open.
- `FILE*` functions work. However, it isn't happy with reads and writes on the same handle; it screws up the seeks. I had to have two separate descriptors and two separate `FILE*`s.
- I had to disable `O_NONBLOCK`.

Arduino driver programmers be warned!

Comment: Arduino will reboot every time you connect through serial. This is done to invoke the bootloader which is used to upload programs to Arduino, without using a dedicated programmer.

Answer (score 1):

Since the arduino uses and FTDI chip you could also use [libftdi](http://www.intra2net.com/en/developer/libftdi/). It makes configuring the baudrate and other features much simpler.

Most linux distros will have libftdi in their repositories.